# Why iso cluster unsupervised classification detect less clases than desired?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, classification

I have this RGB jpg georeferenced map image:

[image]

When I do unsupervised classification with 5 classes

[image]

It only gives 4 classes

[image]

[image]

The original image was generated from CS6 and is georeferenced.

Comment: What do mean minimun class size and sample interval?

Comment: Why are you performing an isocluster on an obviously classified image? Some software spits out multi-channel images for certain image formats. The image should have been exported from Photoshop as a single band greyscale TIFF image and not an RGB JPEG.

Comment: I exported it as Tiff from CS6, it's still and rgb image.

Comment: I have to agree with @JeffreyEvans. Could you please expand why you are wanting to do an IsoCluster Analysis on an already classified image? If you could expand on what you are looking to accomplish perhaps someone can assist and even provide an alternative workflow to get to the desired result.

Comment: It is saving as multi-band because you are saving as RGB or CMYK out of photoshop. Export as a 8 or 16 bit greyscale tiff.

Comment: I want to know the pixel count of each class in the raster of that image. I want to have attribute table tha tells me how many pixels per class there are, assuming I can convert that rgb to a raster.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet to get the pixel count per class would be run the "Reclass" Tool on the original Image.

Choose the number of classes to be 5. You can manually choose the classes if you wish, although from the image shown you should be able to use the default settings.

Run the Tool and you should be able to Open an attribute table with the values of the Classes and the number of Pixels per class.

A second option, although untested, would be to the the "int()" function in the Raster Math Tool in Spatial Analyst. This will convert the Raster into a 5 classed integer raster.